# Sorting lists- a pythonic way

Tags: python-2.7

Sorting two lists `(a, b)` according to `a` and returning back two sorted lists separately as exactly done below is correct.

```
a = ['apple','carrot','banana']
b = [5,10,15]

s = sorted(zip(a,b))
a,b = map(list, zip(*s))

print a
print b

['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']
[5, 15, 10]
```

But, any better ways to do this?
`Given condition: Two lists, a and b.`
`Result: As printed above`

PS This is Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way because I have an aversion to `map`, but it isn't obviously superior to your way. My reason is simply that list comprehensions are readily understood by most Python programmers, but functional programming concepts less so, since the language isn't really set up for functional programming.

```
In [6]: a = ['apple','carrot','banana']

In [7]: b = [5,10,15]

In [8]: A, B = (list(e) for e in zip(*sorted(zip(a,b))))

In [9]: A
Out[9]: ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']

In [10]: B
Out[10]: [5, 15, 10]
```